# Heuristic formula to compute geodesic deviation for rays close to a galaxy

Tags: general-relativity, geodesics, gravitational-lensing

I'm looking for a way to quickly estimate geodesic deviation of light rays passing close to a galaxy. For simplicity I'm assuming the geodesic is passing through the center of the galaxy and leaving with an azimuthal angle $\phi$, so one can approximate the disk as having nearly constant density $\rho_{g}$, thickness $T_g$ and radius $R_g$

Should [the weak field limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic_deviation#Weak_field_limit) of the disk be representative of geodesic deviation to be used for this calculation or is too simplistic for realistic gravitational lensing?

More importantly, is there a formula somewhere where this calculation has already been performed?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your link I think you are convolving two ideas.  Geodesic deviation approximates geodesics near a base geodesic.  Such an equation may be valid in the presence of "strong" fields as long as the neighboring geodesics are in a small neighborhood of the original or base geodesic.  Think of being near a stable minimum configuration.  This technique has been used to approximate orbital parameters of "irregular" orbits.  For light beams traveling through refractive space-times the concept of a deviation vector can be mapped to the instantaneous rate of change of the spreading of the ray bundle, e.g. the small deviation in position (x, y, z, t) expressed in terms of the partial derivatives of the coordinates with respect to initial conditions on the base ray path.  The result can be used to estimate intensity of a light beam.

From a computational perspective you can view the geodesic deviation equation as augmenting the ray (or geodesic) equation.  Given a metric, calc connection and curvature tensors.  Set up initial conditions for the base geodesic, an orthonormal geodesic-centric basis, and the rate of spreading.  The complete set of coupled ODE's can be solved all at once (imposing on shell constraints either in the equations or as a numeric check with each step).  If you have considerable symmetry in the problem the system will reduce in complexity (Killing vectors can be used to reduce order, etc).

If you have an exact solution for your initial geodesic as a function of initial conditions then you should be able to calculate the variation by hand, no need for the second order non-linear deviation equation.

It is my understanding that astrophysicists rarely use the geodesic deviation equation to calculate light intensity.  As I've been told (c. 2001) "the universe is mostly flat with speed bumps here and there" so Fermat's principle is used.  The deviation can be mapped to properties of the deflection sources (refraction), so observations compared to models are used to infer what might be out there.  Is your problem a purely forward propagation problem?  Or a data analysis problem?

As for sources of information I'd recommend Hawking and Ellis Large Scale Structure of Space-Time for a theoretical derivation of the deviation equation and Gravitational Lenses by Schneider, P., Ehlers, J., Falco, E.E. for simplified equations for describing the deformation of the cross section of a ray bundle.  Rather than jumping to an approximation that seems "simple" I'd try and understand the symmetry of the problem and see how that constrains the deviation.  You may be lucky and get an exact solution for your problem.  And if you neglect terms w/o some numerical estimate the result could be erroneous.